# Match Both text with Regex Lookahead on javascript

Tags: javascript, regex-lookarounds

With this regular expression :

```
/lorem(?=[\s,;\[\]\(\)]*ipsum)/ig
```

It matches "lorem" that is followed by "ipsum" with/without " ,;][)(" characters.

Example text: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem; ipsum dolor sit amet, Lorem,; (ipsum) dolor sit amet, Lorem dolor sit amet, Lorem amet.

if I use ?: instead of ?= it matches whole text from "lorem" to end of "ipsum" such as "**Lorem ipsum**", "**Lorem; ipsum**", "**Lorem,; (ipsum**" , etc... .

Now I want to Regex match both "lorem" and "ipsum" without matching " ,;][)(" characters. How I modify the expression to do this?

Comment: should it match "lorem" and "ipsum" in separate groups?

Comment: Yes but it seems that javascript not support grouping in lookahead. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

```
/lorem(?=[\s,;\[\]\(\)]*(ipsum))/gmi
```

demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/HgROFb/1)

Comment: @Vasdu in the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/HgROFb/1) it works on php & python but not works on javascript. why?

Comment: (lorem)(?:[\s,;\[\]\(\)]*)(ipsum) try this one for js

Comment: there are 2 groups , the non capturing group is part of the full match  , you can use the other 2 groups that match lorem & ipsum

Comment: How I use the other 2 groups on js? Is it possible to give me a sample code?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/wf84czxy/  group 1 is "lorem"  and group 2 is "ipsum" and group 0 is full match